# Is it allowed to ask about learning methodologies on SO?

Tags: asking-questions, support

Can I ask questions on Stack Overflow about how to learn creating a CMS with PHP/CodeIgniter?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, I'd say such questions too quickly devolve into a shopping list recommendation and/or are too vague and overly broad.

Instead, while learning, try out different pieces of code and ask questions about the concrete problems you face with those focused tasks.

It could be that 'how do I learn tech X' questions are on-topic at Programmers, but do check their [FAQ](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/faq) first before you ask.

Comment: I'm planning to begin with CodeIgniter, starting from tutorials. I already googled but found some basic stuff. Can I ask questions about what others would recommend?

Comment: @Le3jeb: No, because that's a shopping list recommendation, a non-constructive question. It would be closed.

Comment: @Le3jeb: Thank *you* for taking the time to ask about this first! :-)

Answer (score 1):

It's clear in [FAQ panel](https://stackoverflow.com/faq#questions) about what type of questions one can ask on Stack Overflow:

[image: image of toolbar at top of page]

> What kind of questions can I ask here?
>
> Stack Overflow is for professional and enthusiast programmers, people who write code because they love it. We feel the best Stack Overflow questions have a bit of source code in them, but if your question generally covers …

```
a specific programming problem
a software algorithm
software tools commonly used by programmers
practical, answerable problems that are unique to the programming profession
```

> then you’re in the right place to ask your question!